# Getting an error while deploy a flask application to the web with AWS amplify

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-amplify

I am not receiving any error messages while deployment. It says that Deployment is successful but when I try to access the aws amplify link my web app does not load but instead shows an error as "No webpage was found for the web address. HTTP error 404".

When I tried debugging the issue, here is what I found in the Build log:

```
                                 ## No backend environment association found, continuing...
Starting Frontend Build
                                 # Starting phase: build
                                 # Completed phase: build
2023-07-06T12:41:23.066Z [INFO]: ## Build completed successfully
2023-07-06T12:41:23.067Z [INFO]: # Starting caching...
2023-07-06T12:41:23.067Z [INFO]: Nothing to cache
2023-07-06T12:41:23.067Z [INFO]: # Caching completed
2023-07-06T12:41:23.069Z [INFO]: # No custom headers found.
**2023-07-06T12:41:23.083Z [WARNING]: !! No index.html detected in deploy folder: /codebuild/output/src3464593922/src/digital-me/**
2023-07-06T12:41:23.083Z [INFO]: # Starting build artifact upload process...
2023-07-06T12:41:23.380Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifacts.zip'...
2023-07-06T12:41:23.409Z [INFO]: # Uploading build artifact '__artifactsHash.zip'...
2023-07-06T12:41:23.579Z [INFO]: # Build artifact upload completed
2023-07-06T12:41:23.580Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2023-07-06T12:41:23.580Z [INFO]: # Uploading environment cache artifact...
2023-07-06T12:41:23.696Z [INFO]: # Uploaded environment cache artifact
2023-07-06T12:41:23.697Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

These are the Build and test settings in the aws amplify.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA436.png)

Please let me know what do I need to implement in order to get the Flask app running successfully on the aws server.